# Get variable name of object from an ArrayList

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist, components

I am creating an ArrayList of JTextFields using the following code.

```
ArrayList<JTextField> cmp = new ArrayList<>();
cmp.add(txtAmount);
cmp.add(txtBillTo);
cmp.add(txtBranch);
```

After passing this ArrayList into a method, I need to print the "variable name" of the textfield. I can use the SetName and GetName to print some names. But I need the output as txtAmount, txtBillTo, txtBranch.

Is there anyway to find the variable name of textfield?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for would require reflection of method code, something supported by languages such as Scala via macros/compile time reflection.  However Java itself does not support runtime or compile time reflection of method code, only runtime reflection of classes/fields/functions, although some people have pulled together their own Java parsers to grab the information from source files and others have pulled the information from the Class files debug information.  Neither of which has an officially supported API.

Your best bet is to place the name that you want along with the field, which is obviously duplication and thus could diverge by accident but your options are limited.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this. The information you are asking for is just not recorded. The only way to do it would be to store it yourself:

```
Map<String, JTextField> cmp = new HashMap<>();
cmp.put("txtAmount",txtAmount);
cmp.put("txtBillTo", txtBillTo);
cmp.put("txtBranch", txtBranch);
```

If you need to keep things in the same order you put them into the collection then use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap` as the `HashMap` may change the order.